# Apache of CentOS 7.2 can not be uninstalled

Tags: linux, apache, centos

I want to uninstall Apache of CentOS 7.2,steps are as follow:
**1、# systemctl stop httpd.service** //Actually,httpd is not running.
**2、# rpm -qa|grep httpd** //There is nothing，so, use：
**# yum list|grep httpd**   //content is as follow：

```
darkhttpd.x86_64                        1.11-1.el7                     epel     
httpd.x86_64                            2.4.6-40.el7.centos            base     
httpd-devel.x86_64                      2.4.6-40.el7.centos            base     
httpd-itk.x86_64                        2.4.7.01-5.el7                 epel     
httpd-manual.noarch                     2.4.6-40.el7.centos            base     
httpd-tools.x86_64                      2.4.6-40.el7.centos            base     
libmicrohttpd.i686                      0.9.33-2.el7                   base     
libmicrohttpd.x86_64                    0.9.33-2.el7                   base     
libmicrohttpd-devel.i686                0.9.33-2.el7                   base     
libmicrohttpd-devel.x86_64              0.9.33-2.el7                   base     
libmicrohttpd-doc.noarch                0.9.33-2.el7                   base     
lighttpd.x86_64                         1.4.39-1.el7                   epel     
lighttpd-fastcgi.x86_64                 1.4.39-1.el7                   epel     
lighttpd-mod_geoip.x86_64               1.4.39-1.el7                   epel     
lighttpd-mod_mysql_vhost.x86_64         1.4.39-1.el7                   epel     
opensips-httpd.x86_64                   1.10.5-3.el7                   epel     
owncloud-httpd.noarch                   8.0.10-1.el7                   epel     
python-sphinxcontrib-httpdomain.noarch  1.4.0-1.el7                    epel     
radicale-httpd.noarch                   1.1.1-1.el7                    epel     
viewvc-httpd-fcgi.noarch                1.1.24-1.el7                   epel     
viewvc-httpd-wsgi.noarch                1.1.24-1.el7                   epel     
web-assets-httpd.noarch                 5-1.el7                        epel
```

**3、# yum erase httpd.x86_64**

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks
No Match for argument: httpd.x86_64
No Packages marked for removal
```

## add:

**# yum info httpd**

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks
Available Packages
Name        : httpd
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.4.6
Release     : 40.el7.centos
Size        : 2.7 M
Repo        : base/7/x86_64
Summary     : Apache HTTP Server
URL         : http://httpd.apache.org/
License     : ASL 2.0
Description : The Apache HTTP Server is a powerful, efficient, and
            : extensible web server.
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

Do You really have apache? :)

Try:

```
yum info httpd
```

and check if apache is already installed :)

rpm -qa | grep apache - should found package

Comment: Thanks!   I have added the result of `# yum info httpd`,what does the result mean?

Comment: That means: package is avilable but not installed yet. You don`t have apache :) try install (yum install httpd), after do rpm -qa | grep http and yum info httpd  - You see diffrence :) Finally yum erase httpd to remove.